# What is this statement mean "It is connected but not path-connected."

Tags: general-topology, terminology

What is this statement mean "It is connected but not path-connected."

For example. topologist's sine curve is one of the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space.  To say that $X$ is *connected* is to say that there are no (non-empty) open sets $U,V\subset X$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $U\cup V=X$.

To say that $X$ is *path-connected* is to say that for every pair of points $x,y\in X$, there exists a continuous map $\varphi: [0,1]\rightarrow X$ such that $\varphi(0)=x$ and $\varphi(1)=y$.

As you point out, the topologists' sine curve is one of the typical examples to exhibit that being connected need not imply path-connectedness, though the converse does hold: path-connectedness always implies connectedness.